# How to group record equally using SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Can Some help to figure the output of this record using SQL. I want to group the record equally base on Nth record. On Example below all are divide by 4 equally.

Actual Record

```
SO #    RowNum
001      1
002      2
003      3
004      4
005      5
006      6
007      7
008      8
009      9
010     10
011     11
012     12
013     13
```

Desired Output

```
SO #    RowNum    Group
001      1          1
002      2          1
003      3          1
004      4          1
005      5          2
006      6          2
007      7          2
008      8          2
009      9          3
010     10          3
011     11          3
012     12          3
013     13          4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `rownum` just use arithmetic:

```
select t.*, 1 + ((rownum - 1) / 4) as grp
from t;
```

If not, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, 1 + ((row_number() over (order by rownum) - 1) / 4) as grp
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select a.*,case when RowNum<=4 then 1
              when RowNum<=8 then 2
               when RowNum<=12 then 3
               else 4 end as grp from table_name a
```